# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

/17781b877d5b089c3644ae29c20f0b88/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

i created new project in android studio that promt me to update the kotlin plugin
when i updated then it start giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

in (dependencies) inside build.gradle(project) convert from 1.5.20

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"`

to `1.7.10`

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"`

Comment: Can you post you gradle file app and project level? I am using 1.7.10 version but still getting same error.